# Did Obi-Wan ever find out about Anakin going to Tatooine during Ep. II?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, obi-wan-kenobi, anakin-skywalker

We know Anakin told Palpatine about his stop in Tatooine during AOTC because Palpatine tells him he doesn't have to pretend around him since he knows about the massacre at the Tusken village. But there seems to be no indication of anyone else knowing about him (Anakin) visiting Tatooine and seeing his family.

I have been trying to find if there is any canon information on this: **Did Obi-Wan ever find out about Anakin's time in Tatooine during Ep. II?**

At the very least I wonder if Obi-Wan ever found out wether Anakin knew about the Larses or not. Since it's Yoda the one to say it and I could see the Jedi Order/ Republic Army having this information but not telling it to Anakin.

Did he know before taking Luke there? Did Owen and Beru surprise him by asking about Anakin? (considering that if Anakin had not gone there he shouldn't have known he had a step brother) Did he take Luke there BECAUSE he knew Anakin had been there before with Padmé?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obi-Wan was well aware that Anakin had traveled to Tatooine (and the ostensible reason for his visit and the fact that he'd spent time with his mother before she died as well as the identities of his family) but was unaware of what had happened between Anakin and the Tuskens.

> “Anakin, no!” Obi-Wan shouted as Anakin started forward. Anakin almost
>   hesitated. But **Obi-Wan didn’t know about Tatooine and the Tusken
>   Raiders. Obi-Wan must never know.** And the only way to keep him from
>   seeing Anakin in the same mindless rage was for Anakin to charge now,
>   while he still had control of himself.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Attack of the Clones - Official Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

and

> “On his way to Naboo,” Obi-Wan said. “He is escorting Senator Amidala home.” **Anakin had told him of Shmi’s death; that was why he and Padmé had gone to Tatooine, he said. Obi-Wan had talked to Padmé later, and she had explained that Shmi had been kidnapped and killed by Tusken Raiders.
>
>   Neither of them had been willing to go into much detail, and from what Obi-Wan knew of the Tusken Raiders, he didn’t blame them. It was no wonder Anakin seemed shaken, if his mother had been tortured and killed.** One day, perhaps, Anakin would be willing to tell him the whole story.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Attack of the Clones - Official Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

---

Notably, not only does Obi-Wan know the identities of Anakin's family, but it would appear that he has intel on them from *after* the point that Anakin left the planet in the previous film.

> ***“Cliegg Lars still lives on Tatooine, I think-and Anakin’s stepbrother
>   … Owen, that’s it, and his wife, Beru, still work the moisture farm
>   outside Mos Eisley …”***
>
> “As close to kinfolk as the boy can come,” Yoda said approvingly. “But
>   Tatooine, not like Alderaan it is-deep in the Outer Rim, a wild and
>   dangerous planet.”
>
> “Anakin survived it,” Obi-Wan said. “Luke can, too. And I can-well, I
>   could take him there, and watch over him. Protect him from the worst
>   of the planet’s dangers, until he can learn to protect himself.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization))</sup></sub>